# Передача параметров в css-анимацию

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animation

```
p {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: slidein;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%; 
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Для приведенного выше кода CSS анимации, мне интересно, есть ли способ передать значения `margin-left` и `width` в качестве параметра из Javascript.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Passing parameters to css animation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49750473/7394871) от участника  [@Qian Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1663023/qian-chen).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/users/1663023/qian-chen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или например вот так:

```js
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[1][1].style.background='red'
```

```css
.blue {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 30px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  animation: animation 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes animation {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    background: blue;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(300px, 0);
    background: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Используйте переменные CSS, и вы легко можете это сделать:

```js
document.querySelector('.p2').style.setProperty('--m','100%');
document.querySelector('.p2').style.setProperty('--w','300%');
```

```css
.p1,.p2 {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: slidein;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: var(--m, 0%);
    width: var(--w, 100%);
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="p1">
 This will not animate as the animation will use the default value set to the variable
</p>
<p class="p2">
  This will animate because we changed the CSS variable using JS
</p>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49750566/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>